# Determining existence of limit with multiple variables: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)} \frac{x\ln(y)}{x^2+\ln^2(y)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to determine the limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)} \frac{x\ln(y)}{x^2+\ln^2(y)}$$
If we try to evaluate the limit along $y=e^{mx}$ curves, we find the result to be $$\frac{m}{1+m^2}$$
For different curves (with different $m$), the limit will have different values. Therefore, I concluded that the limit doesn't exist. However, I was trying to be sure, so I searched for different online tools to evaluate this type of limit. I found a widget by Wolfram Alpha that determines the limit to be 0.
[image]

Here it is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd

Is this true? Or what I found earlier was true?

Comment: You are right, Wolfram is wrong

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it was mentioned in the comments: you are right. Wolfram probably just computes the iterated limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{x \log y}{x^2+\log^2 y}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cdot 0}{x^2 +0}= 0
$$

and

$$
\lim_{y\to 1}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x \log y}{x^2+\log^2 y}\right) = \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{0 \cdot \log y}{0 + \log^2y}= 0
$$

But the existence of the iterated limits does not imply the existence of limit.

Comment: Thank you very much.